# Pass data between MATLAB R2011b and Python (Windows 7)

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, parameter-passing, language-interoperability

Hello Friends,

I want to pass data between **MATLAB and Python**, One way would be to use **matlab.engine** in Python or Call Python Libraries from MATLAB. But this approach requires **MATLAB 2014** Version unlike mine which is MATLAB **R2011b.**

So I request you to please guide for a different Approach in order to comunicate between Python and MATLAB R2011b Version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Both [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) support [hdf5](/questions/tagged/hdf5) binary file format.
You can read/write hdf5 data files in matlab using [`hdf5read`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5read.html)/[`hdf5write`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5write.html):

```
>> hdf5write('./data_from_matlab.h5', '/data', x);
```

In python you have [`h5py`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/):

```
import h5py, numpy as np

with h5py.File('./data_from_matlab.h5', 'r') as R:
    x = np.array(R['data'])
```

The other way around:

```
import h5py, numpy as np

with h5py.File('./data_from_python.h5', 'w') as W:
    W.create_dataset(name='data', data=np.zeros((10,10),dtype='f4'))
```

And reading in Matlab

```
>> data = hdf5read('./data_from_python.h5','/data');  % you might need to remove '/' from '/data'...
```

Comment: Thank Shai for quick Response. I tried but I was just able to create .h5 file in MATLAB but when tried to read in Ipython, I wasnt able to...Error was OSERROR: Unable to open the file

Comment: @Abhishek does the file exist? do you have read permissions to the file created? is it possible the file is corrupted? if you type in shell `h5ls <filename>` what do you see?

Comment: Yes, I created in MATLAB and when I entered in cmd...It gave the path and data with { 10, 10}

Comment: Now I cross checked, file is present in the Location but unable to open in python

Comment: with h5py.File(''(Complete link with '/' separation)./data_from_matlab.h5', 'r') as R:
    x = np.array(R['(Complete link with '/' separation) data'])                                                                                                                       but got KeyError: 'Unable to open object(Component not found)'

Comment: Sorry Shai.....I entered ls -ltrh in Ipython...Volume in drive C is SYSTEM Volume Serial Number is 64E0-8641                                                                                                                      Directory of (Link)

Comment: @Abhishek what is `"''(Complete link with '/' separation)./data_from_matlab.h5',`?

Comment: Complete link means Link to the Folder....Okay This is what I mean G:/computer/Abhishek_HonnavalliPuttaiah/Input_Signals/Processing

Comment: @Abhishek you need "complete link/path" only for the file name, when you access the variable in `R`, you only need the variable name: `R['data']` and not `R[full/path/data]` - this is the reason for `KeyError` you get.

Comment: @Shai....I edited and tried on Ipython but still gave Key Error . Unable to open object (Object 'mean.xlsx' doesn't exist)

Comment: @Abhishek what R.keys() gives you?

Comment: AttributeError : 'File ' object has no Attribute 'key'

Comment: @Abhishek what about R['/data']?

Comment: In my case data is mean.xlsx . So I gave R['/mean.xlsx' ] but Value Error: Not a location

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do and your type of data, you could write it to a file and read from it in the other language. You could use `numpy.fromfile` for that in the python part.

Comment: Thanks UpSampler for creative Approach. Actually  my actually Format of the data file is .dat .       So how to read such a file, I tried xls way of importing but didnt work becasue file size was 350MB